# How to use snprintf instead of strcpy in this situation?

Tags: c, string, unix

```
void put(char* key, int value)
{
int i = 0;

// Iterate through elements of hashtable
while (array[i].flag == 1)
{
    // If key already exists, update the value
    // and return
    if (strcmp(array[i].data->key, key) == 0)
    {
        array[i].data->value = value;
        return;
    }

    i = i + 1;

    // Error Handling, when end of hashtable is reached
    if (i == max)
    {
        i = 0;
        // p rintf("\n Hash table is full, cannot insert any more item \n");
        // return;
    }
}

// Insert new item into the hashtable
array[i].flag = 1;

array[i].data = (struct item*) malloc(sizeof(struct item));
array[i].data->key = (char *)malloc((strlen(key)+1)*sizeof(char));
// so here I have to use snprintf instead of strcy because it's
// forbidden, and I don't know how
**strcpy(array[i].data->key, key);**
//snprintf(array[i].data->key,sizeof(key),"%s",key);

array[i].data->value = value;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say "it's forbidden". It means you can not use `strcpy` or when you use strcpy, your program failed ?

Comment: OT, how can you declare struct item ?

Comment: `snprintf(array[i].data->key, strlen(key),"%s",  key);`

Comment: I am not allowed to use strcpy. I must use snprintf

Comment: @Eraklon `snprintf(array[i].data->key, strlen(key),"%s", key);` is off by 1.  Perhaps you meant `snprintf(array[i].data->key, strlen(key) + 1,"%s", key);`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, never cast `malloc`, and do not forget verify the return value of `malloc`.

```
array[i].data = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
if (!array[i].data) {
    // handle error
    return; // for example
}

array[i].data->key = malloc((strlen(key)+1)*sizeof(char));
if (!array[i].data->key) {
    // handle error
}
```

Using `strlen` instead of `sizeof` that returns the size of pointer, not the length of string:

```
snprintf(array[i].data->key, strlen(key) + 1,"%s", key);
```

Comment: Nice answer. I mis-read it the first time and thought it had the wrong functionality and so post my own - with got in a bit deep..

Comment: Thanks. I try to answer the question in order to improve my knowledges and practice the english.

Answer (score 0):

> here I have to use `snprintf` instead of `strcy` because it's forbidden, and I don't know how

`strcpy()` can overflow is the destination is insufficient.  That really does not apply here as the needed space is allocated.

```
// array[i].data = (struct item*) malloc(sizeof(struct item));
// array[i].data->key = (char *)malloc((strlen(key)+1)*sizeof(char));
// strcpy(array[i].data->key, key);

array[i].data = malloc(sizeof *(array[i].data));
size_t sz = strlen(key) + 1;
array[i].data->key = malloc(sz);
snprintf(array[i].data->key, sz, "%s", key);
// or 
strcpy(array[i].data->key, key);
// or 
memcpy(array[i].data->key, key, sz);
```

1. Cast not needed
2. size of of referenced data better to use that sizeof type.
3. Avoid 2 trips finding the length.
4. Returns check omitted for brevity.

---

With checks

```
array[i].data = malloc(sizeof *(array[i].data));
if (array[i].data == NULL) return fail; // or do something to indicate error

size_t sz = strlen(key) + 1;
array[i].data->key = malloc(sz);
if (array[i].data->key == NULL) return fail;

int count = snprintf(array[i].data->key, sz, "%s", key);
if (count < 0 || (unsigned) count >= sz) return fail;
```

---

**Primary mistake**

OP's attempt fails as `sizeof(key)` is the size of a *pointer*, perhaps 2, 4 or 8.  Instead, what is needed is the size of the allocation for `array[i].data->key` as in `sz` (see above) or `strlen(key) + 1`.

```
snprintf(array[i].data->key,sizeof(key),"%s",key); // bad
```